# Laravel миграция использует разные базы

Tags: php, laravel, .env

есть два конфига, .env.dev и .env.prod, в них указаны различные базы

```
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=*
DB_DATABASE=default
DB_USERNAME=*
DB_PASSWORD=*
```

при запуске `php artisan migrate:status --env=production` несколько раз результаты разные - из них очевидно что часть запросов уходит в dev, часть в prod. Как такое вообще может быть, и откуда начинать копать?
Кеш чистил.

Comment: а просто .env есть? Пробовали один из конфигов удалить?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще это выглядит так - `artisan --env=production migrate`

Но раньше эта команда не работала. Не знаю как насчет последних версий. Одно из решений - в файле `config\database.php` скопировать настройки для `mysql` и переименовать их в `mysql_dev`, например

```
    'mysql_dev' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DEV_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DEV_DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DEV_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DEV_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DEV_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DEV_DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

И использовать команду `php artisan migrate --database=mysql_dev`